# Android : Android Activity Launch Error

Tags: android, android-activity

I Have searched for the problem and couldn't find solution for my problem, please help me with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.androidpractise"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

     <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidpractise.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.androidpractise.Second"
            android:label="@string/second_app">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SECOND"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
     </application>

 </manifest>
```

What is wrong with the above code i get

```
[2014-08-27 10:34:24 - AndroidPractise] No Launcher activity found!
[2014-08-27 10:34:24 - AndroidPractise] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

instead of

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SECOND"/>
```

**If you want to launch MainActivity then do this**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.androidpractise.Second"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.androidpractise.Second"
        android:label="@string/second_app">
    </activity>
```

Or if you want to launch Second class then do this...

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidpractise.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.androidpractise.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/second_app">
        </activity>
```

The launcher category should always have

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Comment: @Subbu Glad to help. you can accept the answer if its helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

```
    <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity 
       android:name="com.example.androidpractise.Second"
       android:label="@string/second_app">

                </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add [category_launcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) to your main activity, not `android.intent.category.DEFAULT`. action.main always work with category_launcher

Answer (score 0):

Add this to a Launcher activity

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Code for second activity as a launcher would be

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
  <application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name="com.example.androidpractise.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

</activity>
<activity 
    android:name="com.example.androidpractise.Second"
    android:label="@string/second_app">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name="com.example.androidpractise.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity 
    android:name="com.example.androidpractise.Second"
    android:label="@string/second_app">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SECOND"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code

```
   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
     android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

     <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
    android:name="com.example.androidpractise.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity 
       android:name="com.example.androidpractise.Second"
       android:label="@string/second_app">

                </activity>
              </application>
```